# Generalizing an Eclipse product configuration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

My current situation is that I have about 20 different Eclipse product configurations for an RCP-Application, which contain different features. But all configurations share, for example, the same JVM-Args.

The obvious problem here is, that if the JVM-Args change, I have to change them in every single product file.

Now my question: is there a functionality to centralize or generalize identical configurations across multiple product configurations?

Comment: I don't think Eclipse has anything, but .product files are just XML so you could edit them all with any XML processor

Comment: I also think that this is not possible. [Eclipse itself does not use such generalization for its 14 IDE packages](https://git.eclipse.org/c/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages.git/tree/packages). Please note, that such generalization would violate the principle of self-containment of a product. I tried it with an external XML entity, but that is not allowed in Tycho.